# Test build of Cocoa application not compatible with tester's version of OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, core-data, interface-builder, compatibility

I've been building a basic Cocoa application with Core Data and Interface Builder, and no extra coding, frameworks, or header files.  I sent it to someone to test on their machine (a last-gen G5 iMac), and they got a message saying that their machine couldn't run it.  I discovered the switch to compile for PPC, so I built a PPC version of the application to try out, and that produced the following error message:

> You cannot use this version of `Application` on this version of Mac OS X.

I'm running Xcode 3.2.1, Interface Builder 3.2.1, and OS 10.6.2.  The conversation with my tester was a bit confusing; at first it sounded like she only had Tiger on her machine, saying Leopard was incompatible (I corrected and said that Leopard should be, it's *Snow* Leopard that isn't), and then by the end of the conversation she was about certain that her machine was running Leopard, but had already shut it off by then.  So I'm not sure which version of OS X is on the offending iMac, but it's the latest version of either 10.4.11 or 10.5.8 (the tester is in a remote location, so I can't verify personally at the moment).

What can I tweak to try and improve compatibility on my tester's machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're seeing that message, it's most likely because your app has the LSMinimumSystemVersion key (Minimum system version) set in the Info.plist.  You should take this key out or set it to the actual the minimum OS X version you support.

Once you do this, you may well run into the next problem. (Probably a dynamic linker error as a result of using a framework or API that didn't yet exist on 10.4 or 10.5.)

The main problem here is that you're sending it out to a system where you haven't actually tried it.  If you plan to support 10.4, 10.5, or both, I highly recommend that you find a spare hard drive, partition it up, and install 10.4.11 and 10.5.8.  There are many issues that will crop up on older OS's and if you haven't tried it yourself, it's unlikely it will work smoothly on the first try.

Comment: Found and removed the offending key (have a backup if I change my mind later).  I'm putting the new build together to send over to the tester as I type; check back tomorrow and I'll have an update on how it went.

Comment: All right, just heard back and it's working just fine now.  Also seeing about getting hold of my old Tiger and Leopard install disks to install on my emergency drive for testing purposes.  Thanks a lot!